# Day Tours from Within Kazbegi / Stepantsminda

Tags: georgia-country, day-trips

I am going to visit Stepantsminda (Kazbegi) independently, but was not able to find any organized tours that leave from the town – the ones I found all leave from Tbilisi.

Are there any day tours that leave from Stepantsminda that are bookable online, or an office where they can be booked on-location?

Answer (score 1):

I found tours that can be booked by email, [this company](http://mountainfreaks.ge/en/day-trips-kazbegi/) offers tours (no affiliation) from Kazbegi:

> **The buses depart every day from our office in Stepantsminda (Kazbegi)**. When you are in Kazbegi, visit our office to read the current timetables and join our small expeditions because only with us you have the chance to discover places that ordinary tourists do not reach. **One-day trips can also be booked in advance – write us an e-mail or leave a Facebook message!**

There will probably be other tours offered there.